# can not register a new user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Back end i wrote in node.js and front end in react.js
I want to register a new User to my system.
Register worked if I used Postman, but register not worked at back end

Register.js(react.js):

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:5040';

axios.post('/users/register', newUser)
  .then(res => console.log(res.data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data));

newUser = {name: "test", email: "test0991@gmail.ru", password: "123456", password2: "123456"}
```

Back end:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);

  // Check Validation
  if(!isValid){
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    .then(user => {
      if(user){
        *
      } else {
        *
        *
        *
        );

        const newUser = new User({
          *
          *
          *
          *
        });

        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save()
              .then(user => res.json(user))
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
          });
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

console.log(newUser);
axios.post('/users/register', newUser)
  .then(res => console.log(res.data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err.res.data));
```

Comment: Check the back-end code as the react.js is not receiving response(res.data).

Comment: please add backend code for this route if available

Comment: may be you are not sending data in this particular route , this line clearly shows it `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not sending data. For some reason you use `newUser` when calling `axios.post()`, but you don't assign `newUser` a value until after calling `axios.post()`. The order should be swapped, like this:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:5040';

newUser = {name: "test", email: "test0991@gmail.ru", password: "123456", password2: "123456"}

axios.post('/users/register', newUser)
  .then(res => console.log(res.data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data));
```

Comment: const newUser ={ 
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      password2: this.state.password2
    };



    axios.post('/users/register', newUser)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err.res.data));

Before tried but didn't  worked